# How to do a pulse generator whose pulse width is controlled by a voltage measured in proteus without using a microcontroller or an analog circuit?

Tags: sensor, pulse, proteus, level, hc-sr04

how are you?.

I'm trying to emulate the behavior of the HC-SR04 distance sensor in proteus but using variables.

I succesfully could make a simulation of a water tank whose level is indicating by the voltage of a capacitor and I want that voltage as the parameter that determines the width of the pulse, so, proteus has a pulse component (not VPULSE, only PULSE) which width pulse can be entered as a number. I know that proteus can be used in a way that sheet properties can be used as variables and in some example project they use a voltaje as a variable for a controlled current source but I tried to assign a variable name to the voltage output through a voltage probe then assign that variable name to the pulse width and it didn't work.

I saw this post

[Signal Generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404232/how-can-i-use-a-voltage-to-control-the-pulse-width-of-a-555)

where someone explains how to do something similar to what I want but with OPAMPS and thats is not the objective by the moment though in last instance if I can't archive the way I need then I'll do what they explain in the post.

So, if someone can enlighten me on how to do the pulse width with a voltage as a value (variable) i'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please fix the Pulse Generator link

Comment: Hi @RussellH, sorry for the delay. The link is fixed